# Design pattern or algorithim for updating tree structure represented by several layers of entities

Tags: c#, algorithm, entity-framework, design-patterns

Have a case where I have destination tables that have several "layers" related by FK.

```
Root
    |__A
        |__B
            |__C
                |__D
```

I am importing some data from a flat file, projecting the results into a set of very similar POCO objects.  From there I need to select from these POCO objects and into the entities.  The question is how best to approach updating the entities given that each level can either be new or exists already and needs updated.

For example, the Root object itself might have already been created, but contains no A, therefore A must be created and then its dependent objects added.

Similar, Root might already exist as well as A, but not its dependent B.
Each level has specific fields that need updated, if they already exist.

Answer (score 0):

### Your database

I assume there is a one-to-many relation in your layers: every Root has zero or more As, every A belongs to exactly one Root, using foreign key. Every A has zero or more Bs, every B belongs to exactly one A, using foreign key, etc.

In entity framework you will have something like:

```
class Root
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Root has zero or more As (one-to-many):
    public virtual ICollection<A> As {get; set;}
}
class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every A belongs to exactly one Root, using foreign key
    public int RootId {get; set;}
    public virtual Root Root {get; set;}

    // every A has zero or more Bs:
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs {get; set;}
}
 class B
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every B belongs to exactly one A, using foreign key
    public int AId {get; set;}
    public virtual A A {get; set;}

    // every B has zero or more Cs:
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs {get; set;}
}
etc.
```

> In entity framework the columns of your table are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many)

### Your file

You mention that it can be that you already read a Root1 from your file and read a Root1 again with other children. It seems that your file is flat:

```
Root1, A1, B1, ...
Root1, A1, B2, ...
Root1, A2, B3, ...
Root2, A3, B4, ...
Root1, A4, B5, ...
```

Apparently you have a function to read a "line" of your file:

```
class Line
{
    public Root Root {get; set;}
    public A A {get; set;}
    public B B {get; set;}
    ...
}

IEnumerable<Line> ReadLines(...) {...}
```

### Filling the database

```
void FillDatabase(IEnumerable<Line> lines)
{
    // convert the lines into a sequence or Roots with their As,
    // with their Bs, with their Cs, ...
    IEnumerable<Root> roots = lines.GroupBy(line => line.Root,
        (root, linesOfThisRoot) => new Root
        {
            Name = root.Name,
            ... other root properties
            As = linesOfThisRoot.GroupBy(line => line.A,
            (a, linesWithRootAndA) => new A
            {
                Name = a.Name,
                ... other a properties
                Bs = linesWithRootAndA.GroupBy(line => line.B,
                     (b, linesWithRootAB) => new B
                     {
                        ... B properties
                        Cs = linesWithRootAB.GroupBy(line => line.C,
                        {
                           etc.
                        })
                        .ToList(),
                    })
                    .ToList(),
               })
               .ToList(),
            })
            .ToList();
        });
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext()
    {        
        dbContext.Roots.AddRange(roots.ToList());
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```